# Java Number formatting for many fields in the data object

Tags: java, formatting, biginteger, bigdecimal

I have a data object that is holding a meny BigDecimal object as well as String and other type of object in my data object class. what is the best way to do some common operation on the BigDecimal field like intrest rate

```
interest=interest.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

1. I could do it in the setters/ getter but it could be more erroneous I want to make sure that every variable has been treat by same method.
2. I could have some  helper class that could be called from the setter or setter. I hate to write any code in the helper.

Is there any other good way I could do this ?

Comment: What is the relationship between the BigDecimal, String and other data in you object?

Comment: Thanks a lot ,they are related logically like person is the Object and the first name is String, salary is the BigDecimal ?  I hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the setters for that. If I had to do that to all BigDecimal fields I would consider extend the BigDecimal and code the treatment on the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a static method in the class that formats the BigDecimals as you require?

```
public static BigDecimal formatAs(BigDecimal example) {
    //format here and return it
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
BigDecimal interest = MyClass.formatAs(myInstance.getInterest());

BigDecimal rate = MyClass.formatAs(myInstance.getRate());
```

For as many BigDecimals as you have in your class...

Comment: Thanks this is the helper approach but the problem is when i am going to call it ?

Comment: This was not meant to be in a helper class - directly in whatever class contains all the fields.  I'll edit my answer on how to call.